# class/lib for parallel downloads on iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I need some class or lib that would allow me to run multiple parallel downloads. I didn't have luck finding any, do you guys know about something useful?
I need to add new files to download dynamically, so something that only get initialized with urls at the beginning won't help me much.

I tried to create my own, but I had some [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129080/concurent-background-donwloads-on-iphone) with it. So I figured I would try to get something that is already done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332276/managing-multiple-asynchronous-nsurlconnection-connections) and at this [blog entry](http://blog.emmerinc.be/index.php/2009/03/15/multiple-async-nsurlconnections-example/) which contains sample code that uses NSURLConnection subclass.

Comment: I created similar solution based on this, thanks again for your help!